# Why Javascript Ajax call fails over SSL on IOS devices except IOS 5.

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ajax, ssl

I have a mobile application that makes an ajax xmlHttpRequest request over SSL to another application on the same domain to authenticate a user. This call fails with response code zero on IOS devices prior to IOS 5 and I get told that it cannot reach the domain. It works fine on IOS 5 and desktop browsers. This application uses pure javascript, no jquery or anything like that.

Strangely, I have another application on the same domain that does a similar call over ssl to do it's authentication, and this call is successful on all devices. The only real difference of interest is that this application uses jquery.ajax() to make the call.

Debugging through Charles ssl proxy I got the same error. So, I went directly to the ajax url in the safari address bar. I was then warned about the dodgy Charles certificate and asked if I want to accept it. After doing this, the ajax call always works.. on all devices! Then, I turned off the Charles proxy, and started getting failed ajax calls again. :(

Please can someone advise me on anything they know about:

1. Is there any difference between IOS 5 and previous version of IOS that relates to SSL and could be the cause of this.
2. What does jquery do in their ajax call that could make it work when a standard xmlHttpRequest does not?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a certificate error. The problem was that some browsers accepted the invalid cert and others didn't. Frustrating, but fixing the cert sorted out my problems.